# when is viewDidAppear called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

If I have a UIViewController called B. If I add UIViewController C as a subview/child view controller of B. Then I add in D as a child view controller of B too. I then remove D from B. In this case should C's viewDidAppear be called afterwards?

The reason I ask is because I am not getting B's call to viewDidAppear. I am planning to do something when B's dismissed.

Comment: when you remove B, its viewDidDisappear should be called

Comment: well that's pretty obvious. I am asking about B's viewDidAppear when C's removed from B as a child

Comment: 'viewDidAppear' will get called when the view is fully loaded (i.e after 'viewWillAppear'). It will not get called when you add/remove a sub view!!

Comment: You have `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.  WILL and DID! Its self explanatory.  Its even documented on Apple's website and header files...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`viewDidAppear` will not be called when you dismiss a modal view. Think of a modal view as a view on top on the view.

Answer (score 2):

What I think, viewDidAppear is not called while adding or removing a subview. The reason behind this is, there are several objects which we add/remove to the view as subview. In this, viewDidAppear will be called again and again which is **not** a good mechanism. viewDidAppear is called when you load a class object on the current view and move the screen to another class's view and then return to the previous class. **In short if you Push a navigationcontroller to a new view and then pop it to the older view then viewDidAppear is Called.**

Answer (score 2):

As I tested now `viewDidAppear` is calling when the view come to screen. even 1px. and even if you cover it by any other `subView` and again discover it this method will NOT call again.

It means it will call only after the `subView` appear for the first time. unless you remove it and add it again. in your question `viewdidAppear` of "C" is not calling again after you remove "D".