# iOS KVO - Cannot remove an observer

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I have a simple Viewcontroller that is KVO compliant and has the following in it:

```
  - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];



        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuff" options:0 context:NULL];
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuffFailed" options:0 context:NULL];
        }

    - (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuff"];
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuffFailed"];
      }
```

the issue im having is that sometimes user are reporting the following error:

```
Cannot remove an observer <MyViewController 0x145d0c8d0> for the key path "importStuff" from <MyViewController 0x1741b2280> because it is not registered as an observer.
```

the addObserver call is not called anywhere else in code. is it something about the life cycles im missing ? isn't viewDidAppear guaranteed to be called once (so it should register the keys right ?)

Comment: This is not a safe way to handle KVO. If your app is interrupted by a phone call, then viewWillDisappear won't get called, but viewDidAppear could get called again when the app relaunches. There are many other less than ideal possibilities. You should consider using more reliable methods to add and remove observers (viewDidLoad, dealloc, etc)

Comment: thanks for the knowledge. what happens if i call addObserver  twice ? do i then have to removeObserver twice as well ? Also this article says ViewDidAppear is only called once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534396/when-is-viewdidappear-called

Comment: not answering your question but you could protect yourself from the error with `@try {[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"yourKeyPath"];}
    @catch (NSException * __unused exception) {}`

Comment: @vib no no no no. NO. Do I have to explain that that is really very very bad practice? That does not solve anything and will just cause your program to not work as intended and crash at some later point without indication to why. Not logging exceptions is a very bad idea as well. An exception is an indication that something went wrong that you should take care of and not just ignore.

Comment: @j2emanue your link refers specifically to modals, not all view controllers. You did not specify that your current view controller is a modal. Is this the case? That would be helpful to know but doesn't change the issue I already brought up.

Comment: @luk2302 That's why I did say it was not an answer. And in this particular case, is this really likely to cause a crash later on ?

Comment: @gurooj - its not a modal view i was referring to so your right. So then a phone call interruption would call viewDidDisappear and after the call ends viewDidAppear gets called again right?

Comment: No, there's no guarantee that a viewDidAppear will be matched with a viewWillDisappear every time. It is _very_ bad practice to handle KVO in these methods. Do not attempt! Do it in more documented pairings like viewDidLoad/dealloc

Comment: i like your answer. you can post a offical answer if you please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no guarantee that a `viewDidAppear` will be matched with a `viewWillDisappear` every time. This means your KVO registration/unregistration would potentially be unbalanced and non-deterministic. You should perform KVO registration/unregistration in guaranteed pairings like `viewDidLoad` and `dealloc`.

Comment: I have one doubt in my case controller is observer for some view property. Will the view be available at deinit method of controller?

Comment: @AmberK the view should still be available in the deinit method. It'll probably crash if it isn't, so it should be easy to test.

Answer (score 17):

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) say there is a way to add observer when view is visible only. According to *Figure 1 - Valid State Transitions* you can use pair `viewWillAppear`/`viewWillDisppear` for adding and removing observers. At the same time you can use `init`/`dealloc` pair, but not `viewDidLoad`/`dealloc` - view can be not loaded, but controller deallocated.

Your code should be:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuff" options:0 context:NULL];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuffFailed" options:0 context:NULL];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuff"];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"importStuffFailed"];
}
```